# Json Response in LoadRunner

Tags: json, correlation, loadrunner

I have this Json response:

```
{
    "data": {
            "key": "7316970d1ed2ac72f17cdf481866ec812ae3f9387620bd1cece82567d222786566ebb8b485caf97c",
            "card": {
                    "display_number": "54****5166",
                    "url_image": "75210502455|FIESTA REWARDS CLASICA"
                },
            "card_current_balance": {
                    "currency_code": "MXN",
                    "amount": 21100
                },
            "statements": [
                    {
                        "key": 18,
                        "description": "Corte actual",
                        "transactions": []
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 17,
                        "description": "Del 8 de septiembre al 8 de octubre",
                        "transactions": []
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 16,
                        "description": "Del 9 de agosto al 8 de septiembre",
                        "transactions": [
                                {
                                    "key": 14,
                                    "posted_date": "10/08/2020 12:00:01 a. m.",
                                    "description": "CIA DE GAS DE MORELOS",
                                    "amount": {
                                            "currency_code": "MXN",
                                            "amount": 900
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": 4,
                                    "posted_date": "07/08/2020 12:00:01 a. m.",
                                    "description": "TODO PARA SUS PIES",
                                    "amount": {
                                            "currency_code": "MXN",
                                            "amount": 323
                                        }
                                }
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 15,
                        "description": "Del 8 de julio al 7 de agosto",
                        "transactions": []
                    }
                ]
        },
    "notifications": []
}
```

I need to extract the following data:

```
$.data.statements[*].key
$.data.statements[*].transactions[*].key
```

However, as you can see in the Json some **"Transactions"** are empty, how can I make my LR script discard the empty ones and only extract the first record with both values?
I hope I was clear and thanks for your help.

Comment: Forget to comment that I have more than 1000 json responses with different values and filled in different ways, that's why I can't do it with a simple correlation.

Comment: Why can't you capture the whole thing, then parse it with your own code to populate an array?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried LR JSON api like [lr_json_find](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/2020_SP2-SP3/help/function_reference/FuncRef.htm#FuncRef/c_vuser/lrFr_lr_json_find.htm%3FTocPath%3DUtility%2520Functions%2520and%2520C%2520Language%2520Reference%7CUtility%2520Functions%253A%2520C%2520Language%2520(lr_)%7CAlphabetical%2520Listing%7C_____45)?

The JSON query syntax is explained [here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/2020_SP2-SP3/help/function_reference/FuncRef.htm#LR_JsonPath.htm).